# SQL Between operation in android sqlite date is not working?

Tags: android, android-datepicker, android-date

I am new to android development. I been working on this for one day and i couldn't figure out whats the exact problem is because my query is running without error but no result.

My database query  *Value of formattedDate*

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 

    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

  public Cursor paymentWeek(Activity activity)
    {

         String[] from = { _PAYMENTID, NAME, REQUESTEDDATE, FROMAD, TOADD, EMAILBODYPAYMENT, AMOUNT};  

         SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase(); 

         String orderby = REQUESTEDDATE+" DESC";   

         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + PAYMENTTABLE+ " WHERE " + REQUESTEDDATE + " BETWEEN date('"+formattedDate+"') AND date('"+formattedDate+"','-7 days')", null);

         activity.startManagingCursor(cursor);

         return cursor;  
    }
```

My database date type is `TEXT`. i am storing in the format of (`yyyy-mm-dd`),eg:2012-04-07

But the problem is i can retrieve all datas from the database but if i want to retrieve values for last 7 days it doesn't show any values.

It would be great if any alternatives available? and tip how to go for it?

Thanks...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as you say, your `date` type is `TEXT`, i dont think you can use `between x and y` to make the filter to return the content from `x to y` .

you can try this: http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sql-between-date.shtml or http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/between.php .

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I have solved the problem before seeing your comment.. But your answer is correct.. we cant use between operator.. thanks for your answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + PAYMENTTABLE+ " WHERE " + REQUESTEDDATE + " BETWEEN date('"+formattedDate+"') AND date('"+formattedDate+"-7')", null);
```

Try out this query, you have made a mistake in `date('"+formattedDate+"','-7 days')"`.

Comment: thanks for your comment... I solved the problem. the problem is between operator, i tried < operator and date() function to retrieve my results.. Its worked...